# Remove lines with specific line number specified in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file `A` which contains line numbers which I want to remove from text file `B`. For example, file `A.txt` contains lines

```
1
4
5
```

and file `B.txt` contains lines

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

The resulting file should be:

```
B
C
```

Of course, this can be done manually with

```
sed '1d;4d;5d' B.txt
```

but I wonder how to do it without specifying line numbers manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `awk` as well:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { nums[$0]; next } !(FNR in nums)' linenum infile
```

in specific case when 'linenum' file might empty, awk will skip it, so it won't print whole 'infile' lines then, to fix that, use below command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && FILENAME==ARGV[1]{ nums[$0]; next } !(FNR in nums)' linenum infile
```

or even better (thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](/users/22565)):

```
awk '!firstfile_proceed { nums[$0]; next } 
     !(FNR in nums)' linenum firstfile_proceed=1 infile
```

Answer (score 4):

Use sed to write a sed program.

```
sed "$(sed 's/$/d/' A.txt)" B.txt > C.txt
```

The "program" can be made more elaborate, for example it could validate that the lines are only numbers, or invent a syntax for comments and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, combining basic shell commands:

```
join -v1 <(nl file) line_numbers | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

or:

```
nl file | join -v1 - line_numbers | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Use `nl` to number the lines of the file, and then `join -v1` will keep only lines without match in the second file, finally `cut` the line number. File `line_numbers` has to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat fileA`; do  sed -n ''$i'p' fileB; done >>content.txt
for i in `cat content.txt`; do sed -i '/^'$i'$/d' fileB;done

output
B
C
```

Comment: Running a `sed` for every line in fileA is not going to be fast. There is no requirement to do an in-place edit of fileB. The editing will go very wrong as soon as there is more than one word on a line in fileB due to incorrect quoting.